# Any way to find out what Pirate Treasures I got or not?

Tags: yooka-laylee

I got a few pirate treasures, and in case I forget which one I've got or not, is there somewhere in the game I can see which ones I have and which ones I don't have?

They don't appear on the totals screens, so it's not like quills, pagies and ghosts, where you can know how much you got in each level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only five total Pirate Treasures (one in each world).  As you said, they are not tracked, and as far as I can tell, there isn't any other way to know how many you have.

There are three achievements related to the pirate treasures, one for getting your first one, one for getting three, and one for getting all five.  Although the achievements won't tell you your total if you are at two or four treasures, nor will it tell you which worlds you've missed them in, you can at least have an idea of how many you have.